# LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "django_session"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql

I've created an environment in MacOS. Django version 1.10.6. In Linux every thing is okay, but in MacOS I got this error:

```
ProgrammingError at /
relation "django_session" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "django_session" WHERE "django_sessio...
                               ^
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 1.10.6
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
relation "django_session" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "django_session" WHERE "django_sessio...
```

An important thing is that I can't run migrates in "sites", only in each app.

Comment: This error means that the session executing the query can't "locate" the `django_session` table.  That could come from either the table not existing or the session can't find it.  What happens when you logon using `psql` (postgres included utility) with the same credentials as the query above and try to run the same query?

Comment: Also, you do need to run the migration so the tables are created.  Can you please post your models.py?

Comment: I ran the migrate sites, but the message i'm getting is there's no migrations to apply. when I select in psql I'got the same message "ERROR:  relation "django_session" does not exist". The models.py are okay cause I have the same running on Lunix.